Hardwood Flooring Glue-Assist -- which product is suitable?
I'm installing 5" x 3/4" solid oak hardwood flooring (not engineered!) on a plywood subfloor in a first floor room over a finished basement. The room is <30' wide. I was planning a nail installation, but reading the manufacturer's docs it looks like I should be doing nail + glue-assist to prevent cupping. The manufacturer recommended a specific brand of Urethane glue, and there are other hardwood flooring specific urethane glues in that price range, but they are pretty expensive (Bostick and Mapei come in at ~$0.66/lf).  Is it ok to use a general purpose Polyurethane glue instead, which could cost half as much or less (PL Premium would be ~$0.29/lf)?  PL Premium looks like it has elastic properties for installing subfloors, but how can I tell if it would be enough for attaching hardwood flooring to plywood?
EDIT:
Here are the manufacturer's recommendation:
" an approved wood floor adhesive in cartridge form e.g. Bostik’s Best or Tread-lock. ... For other applications (patterns) of
adhesive, please review the NWFA Guidelines 2020."
So the Bostick's looks just like a brand name drop as an example (unless "e.g." doesn't mean what I thought it meant?), not a hard and fast rule.  Here's what the NWFA Guidelines 2020 says about Glue-Assist:
"The adhesive should be a wood flooring adhesive with elastomeric qualities to allow for normal movement within the flooring system"
... So I guess the question is how do I determine from the glue manufacturer's docs whether it has said elastomeric qualities?

The only opinion that matter here is the manufacturers'.  The wrong glue could void any warranty.

First off, we don't reccommend any products or give advise on which ones to use. You would be very smart to follow the manufacturer's instructions. Using a cheaper, non recommended glue would void any and all warranties that would come with your flooring. You would also be taking a chance of the installation failing at some point in the future. We see that a lot here. Solid oak flooring is expensive. Don't skimp on the adhesive.

Counterpoint: all of these warranties are useless, because they don't cover the labor, which is most of the cost. And I've never seen, heard about, or known anybody who has ever successfully submitted a warranty claim for flooring or roofing materials. So I agree that the risk of failure is a consideration. But the possibility of a warranty should not.

Yeah, I'm pretty sure any claim I would submit would be denied as a problem with installation. This is the DIY forum after all. I'm mostly concerned about finding a less expensive product that will hold up for 20 years.

If you are not worried about voiding a claim to the manufacturer, use whatever glue you want.  It's your floor.
